# Best method for networking Docker containers with Postgres and Nextjs (fetching data from DB at build-time)

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose

I have two docker containers. One `test-app` is made with a Dockerfile that is recommended from Next.js documentation. The other `test-db` is just using the official Postgres image.

When building the image that `test-app` is using, data is fetched from the DB running on `test-db` (using the `getStaticProps` function from Nextjs). So I have to make sure that `test-db` container is running and the DB is ready to accept connections before building the image for `test-app`.

So if I add both containers to the same docker network and then use `test-db` as the hostname for the database, that will not work because there is an error at build time of the Nextjs image that it cannot resolve `test-db` hostname.

**What is working for me is**:

- I start the `test-db` container without adding it to a docker network
- I set the `PGHOST` environment variable used to specify the host of the database for the Nextjs app to the IP address of `test-db` container
- I build the Nextjs app
- I run the `test-app` container without adding it to a docker network
  if I set the `PGHOST` environment variable for the Nextjs app to the IP address of the `test-db` container.

**The problem is**: if I add *either* container to a network the connection between the two containers no longer works. Now, if I set the `PGHOST` to the IP address of `test-db`, I get a connection timed out error.

I would really like to have both on the same Docker network, and just have `PGHOST=test-db`. But at least would like `test-app` to go on **a** Docker network for the future as I plan to add another container that it will interface with.

I have seen people with Nextjs and Postgres containers working using Docker compose so I have tried that. I will paste the `docker-compose.yml` file below. Using Docker compose with the configuration below I get this error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND test-db
```

Is there something wrong with the docker-compose file or is it expected that at build time it still can't use the service name as the host name in docker-compose? And either way is there some way to get this working with/without Docker compose?

```
version: '3'

services:
  test-app:
    container_name: test-app
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      PGHOST: test-db
      PGPORT: 5432
      PGDATABASE: postgres
      PGUSER: postgres
      PGPASSWORD: postgres
    depends_on:
      test-db:
        condition: service_healthy
  test-db:
    container_name: test-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres", "-d", "postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

Comment: How does the data get into the database, before your application is built?  If you build an image, push it to a repository, and I pull it and run it on my machine, will it still work even if my database doesn't have the same data?  Usually your image build shouldn't depend on your database running at all.

Comment: Yeah data is there before the app is built but it works with different data or no data. It does makes sense that the image build should not depend on the database running. But the point of `getStaticProps` is to pre-render the page at build time with data so is it possible to have an image build depend on database, should I just move the database off docker possibly